# What happened when you put two light bulbs to complete the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit, plug

[image]

I have an argument..
In the top section we have two wall plugs hooked up like a common circuit.

In the bottom section if we plug two consumers will it work, will it work half the power or it will blow up?

Comment: Hint: your windows has a screenshot tool, and your keyboard even has a key for that. Oh, and paint is actually a tool to create and save images. This is so low-effort that I'm fighting myself not to give you a down vote...

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I lost the fight.

Comment: @brhans strange – I just did, too.

Comment: Its worse than that, guys.  That's Paint, fer chrissakes.  All he had to do was save the drawing then podt it here.  No screen shot needed.

Comment: Disregarding the primitive drawing , if I understand you , ganging two outlets with same voltage does not raise the voltage but if reversed blows the breaker. But the interesting part is two series bulbs try to divide the voltage in half. Except bulbs made of tungsten that are never perfectly matched. So  that even if one is  0.1% higher resistance they both will start heating up , but the higher R  faster faster towards its 10x resistance at 2500’K, then accelerates faster drawing up to 90% of  the voltage across one bulb only while the other cools  down or just warm giving dim or no light.

Comment: For the record ,the image it was draw with a balltrack on pc from work ,wich i can not download files.

Comment: This website incorporates a tool for drawing simple circuits, you might enjoy trying it. [Edit your question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/382845/edit) and press Ctrl+M (or click the circuit "schematic" icon)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1814/

Comment: A screenshot of a paint drawing, why not just save the drawing and insert it into your post?

Answer (score 2):

If the two outlets are on the same phase then combining them as shown will have NO affect compared to just using one of them.

If the outrlets do not have identical connections them connecting them as shown will cause a blown fuse / tripped breaker / maor damage (choose some).

The bulbs are connected in series. They will usually both operate at reduced output.